# How to improve ListContourPlot quality and resolution?

Tags: plotting

Need help to improve the quality of the `ListContourPlot` below.

```
data = Import[
   "https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkyoamgqop7kpio/data.txt?dl=1", "TSV"];
ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

I need smoother contours and no blank space in the plot. How can I do that? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: There is no magic. Remember the old saying: garbage in — garbage out, so when the data is bad, the plot will be bad.

Comment: The data in this example is the horizontal component of the stresses obtained from a finite element solution of a strip foot problem. Unfortunately the data is avaiable only at the integration points, so it's dificult to obtain a better data without refining the Finite Element Mesh, wich is already very fine.

Comment: There is another issue with your data, it has duplicate points, evaluate `xyPoints = data[[All, {1, 2}]];
{Length@xyPoints,
 Length@DeleteDuplicates[xyPoints]}` to see.

Comment: If the data is jagged, and you want smoother contours, you will need to smooth the data.

Comment: @mikado yes, I'm working on this.